# DOMException when sending audio file using Django

Tags: javascript, django, audio, domexception

I am building a Django based web app in which I want to play an audio file from the server in the browser upon the click of a button. The file changes with the use of the app so I call a Django view through the `src` attribute of the `audio` element like so:

```html
<audio id="audio" src="{% url 'play' 'for-sure' %}" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

Here `for-sure` is the default filename to play. Here's the mapped view function:

```py
def play(request, file_name):
    with open(f'audio/{file_name}.wav', 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), status=206)
        response['content_type'] = 'audio/wav'
        return response
```

I also add a button to play the sound:

```html
<input type="button" value="Play audio" onclick="play()" id="play_btn">
```

And the accompanying Javascript:

```js
function play(){
    var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio");
    var promise = audioElement.play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
      promise.then(_ => {
        console.log('playing')
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('playing error')
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error.message)
      });
    }
  };
```

This works in Firefox (v68), but I keep getting `DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found` in Chromium (v76).

From what I've found it seems to be the AutoPlay prevention policy, but it should be also active in Firefox. If it is, I'm guessing it could be triggered by receiving the HTTP response by the view that wants to autoplay the audio.

I've also tried initing an AudioContext as [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/web-audio-autoplay), and resuming it upon button click but to no avail.

What am I missing and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally I've got it - it wasn't the AutoPlay Policy after all. Chrome doesn't support the audio element's `src` attribute to be the Django view's url (which responds with a HTTP Response audio file transfer). Hence `Failed to load because no supported source was found`.

As a solution, I switched to serving the audio files from my `static` directory setting the `src` to the static file's path. For example, the audio element init that points to the default sound now reads:

```html
<audio id="audio" src="{% static 'annotate/audio/for-sure.wav' %}" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```